# Is it possible to only build certain models?

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

`./symfony propel:build-model` tries to build all models. Is it possible, and if so how, to specify only a certain model?

Comment: Presuming you're running symfony 1.4 with the standard Propel plugin? As far as I know it isn't possible to do this - why do you want to? If you've created custom row/peer classes, they won't be overwritten, and although base classes will be overwritten, that's fine. (Propel without symfony doesn't allow you to do this either from the command line).

Comment: @halfer I was looking for a workaround as my development server exceeded memory. Please post the relevant part of your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Done, thanks. Just checking - you're not doing model builds on a web server, are you? All building should be done on a local computer where memory isn't scarce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want isn't possible to do with Propel at the command line. It *is* possible to do this programmatically (see [this article](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2011/02/generating-propel-1-5-classes-programmatically/) I wrote if you're interested) but it's not as trivial as running a CLI command.

If you are having trouble with memory size, just increase the amount allocated in php.ini. You should be fine with 32-64M, I should think.